# Can numeric keypad zero be used in key binding for Sublime?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext2, key-bindings

I like to assign what I consider the most useful/used shortcut in my IDE or editor to the 0 on the numeric keypad. I find it fast and convenient. I have keypad in NumLock mode but that is fine. I would like to assign Sublime's SH-CTRL-P to this key but I can't seem to do it. I can get close with the PLUS key by using:

```
{ "keys": ["keypad_plus"], "command": "show_overlay", "args": {"overlay": "command_palette"} }
```

I've tried `keypad_zero` and `keypad_0` but neither worked. Can it be done? What's the magic string?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`keypad0` should work. Found by logging input `sublime.log_input(True)` though I think there is a list somewhere too, just to lazy to find it. :)

Comment: Arrgghh, how could I not try it without the underscore? Thanks.

Comment: Knowing it exists made me look harder, I started exploring the _Sublime Text Unofficial Documentation_ and [found the complete list](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/key_bindings.html/#bindable-keys).

Comment: @Tod the link is broken

Comment: @user4050 Here's a [new link to the key_bindings.html](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/key_bindings.html) page/